# Java / Dalvik - Comparing code section execution time

Tags: java, performance, analytics, performance-testing, dalvik

I programming a 60 FPS game and need to find those code sections that are badly affecting the game loop's performance. I'm currently storing a nanosecond timestamp at the start of the frame and split my code into logic parts, for example "Rendering particles" or "Iterate through enemy AIs". After finishing the execution of each section I store the execution time needed to execute code since the last section finished. At the end I retrieve the total execution time ([nanoseconds now] minus [first nanosecond timestamp]) and calculating the percentage of each code section execution time. This allows me to display the percentage taken by each section, but doesn't seem to be the perfect solution. I guess GC randomly affects code section executions.

Is there a better way I can implement or even an API / Analytics Tool for doing exactly this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: Thanks. Bookmarked! I'm using LibGDX which allows writing game logic once and extend platform specific code when deploy for desktop or Android (LWJGL / OpenGL ES). I'd like to optimize the desktop version first, so are there any nice Windows profilers?

Comment: [Visual VM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) is probably the most common.

Comment: Aww, and it's even already contained by the JDK. Tried it out and already found some instances / method calls that could create leaks / lags. VisualVM just doesn't seem to recover field names. Too bad. It will still be a big help though, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the commenters recommended [traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html), which is generally useful for instrumenting code written in Java to figure out what's slow.  It's less useful for a mix of Java and native (because the instrumentation disproportionately slows the Java code), and it lacks useful context when you're trying to figure out if you're meeting or missing deadlines when generating frames with OpenGL.

The preferred way to do this sort of analysis is with systrace ([doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html), [explanation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html)).  As you can see from the second link, you can compare your app timeline directly with the vsync event and surface composition activity.

If you're running Android 4.3 (API 18) or later, you can add your [own events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Trace.html).  Adding these to strategic places in your app makes it much easier to visualize your bottlenecks.  A simple example can be found [here](http://bigflake.com/systrace/).  (As of when I'm writing this, the official docs don't yet describe the 4.3 command-line usage, so it's easiest to just follow the example.)

Android 4.3 also added the "dalvik" tag; if included, your traces will show where the GC pauses start and end, as well as full details on which threads actually got suspended.

Comment: That's exactly what I need for analyzing lag causes. I guess I used the wrong search tags when I tried to find approaches. Thanks!